# How to get the current culture in a controller (in a custom module of Orchard CMS)

Tags: orchardcms, currentculture

I need to get the current culture in a controller in a custom module; I know how to get it from a razor view:

```
@{
    var currentCulture = WorkContext.CurrentCulture;
}
```

but in the controller I have no access to the WorkContext and I can't find anything similar (I tried HttpContext but there is no CurrentCulture method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the `WorkContextAccessor` into your controller and get the current `WorkContext`

```
private readonly IWorkContextAccessor _wca;

public MyController(IWorkContextAccessor wca) {
    _wca = wca;
}

public ActionResult Index() {
    var workContext = _wca.GetContext();
}
```

The `WorkContext` is also available on the `IOrchardServices` interface

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for! And also more general than I expected ...